# Obtain an array (or a labeled vector) from a frequency table in R

Tags: r, frequency

I have a frequency table as follows:

```
group    time    event
a         1       0
a         2       1
a         3       0
a         4       2  
a         5       0
b         1       1
b         2       0
b         3       2
b         4       1
b         5       0
```

and I would like to obtain a table that represents only the times where the event was observed and linked to the group... something like this:

```
group   time (n times, depending how many events occurred for each time)
a       2
a       4
a       4 
b       1
b       3
b       3
b       4
```

I have only obtained a vector with the "rep" function, but I loose the label of the group.
As my original data contains thousands of rows, I really need a quick way to do the job in **R**.
I really appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide the R code that produces these tables? It would make it easier for us to quickly help you. Also, how is the first table a frequency table? (Was it produced using `table()`?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Replicate each row of an R data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518728/r-replicate-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications)

Answer (score 4):

Given your data

```
x <- data.frame(group=c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), 
                time=rep(1:5, 2), 
                event=c(0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2,1,0))
```

You want:

```
x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), x$event), 1:2]
```