# How to repeat strings with respect to count

Tags: r

So what I want is:

```
Some Variable1   Some Variable2       Count 
A                    B                  1
A                    C                  2
B                    C                  3
```

Using `for` loops and `if` statements and possibly with new `data.frame`

What I also want is a 6x2 matrix:

```
Some Variable1     Some Variable2
A                    B
A                    C
A                    C
B                    C
B                    C
B                    C
```

This is my first time using this StackExchange.

Basically What I want is if Count equals 3 and Some Variable1 equals B and Some Variable2 equals C Repeat B and C 3 times.

Please tell me how to do this...I will be very grateful.....

Comment: Please tell me how to do spacing I could not figure it out...

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I want to question by the way.

Comment: 4 spaces in front of "code", but this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks explains it more thoroughly

Comment: Trying to figure out your question. So, you have the first data frame and you want to generate a new one using `Count` to repeat the pair of `Variable`s?

Comment: Yes...That is exactly I want!

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Replicate each row of an R data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518728/r-replicate-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# recreate your data
dat <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "A", "B"), var2 = c("B", "C", "C"), Count = 1:3)
# 
dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$Count),]
#    var1 var2 Count
#1      A    B     1
#2      A    C     2
#2.1    A    C     2
#3      B    C     3
#3.1    B    C     3
#3.2    B    C     3
```

After that you can get rid of the Count column using negative indexing.

Comment: could just do `dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$Count),1:2]` to get rid of `Count`

Comment: Thank you so much! The algorithm makes sense, I will try it now to see if it works.

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you but What if counts are not sequential and if for example counts are random numbers?

Comment: Wow....I asked the redundant question twice. Sorry I am R noobie....I understand now. Thank you very much @Dason

Comment: @user1896642, you may want to check out my [`expandrows` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc/blob/master/R/expandrows.R) which is a convenience function based around this concept. It has an argument called "count.is.col" which, if set to `FALSE` lets you specify a vector for how many times you want to replicate each row.

Comment: @AnandaMahto The problem is my real data is actually "Yes" or "No" instead of "A" "B" "C" but when I coded how Dason told me, it works but if I wanted "Yes" to be 1 and "No" to be 0 so I can run a regression on it how would I do that?

Comment: Hmm I see that factor function solves this problem....wow that was pretty stupid..