# How to perform a logistic regression when dealing with counts rather than individual datas

Tags: r

I am sorry but I really need to know the answer this question...

I am trying to perform logistic regression through R CRAN.

Data is given as follows

```
Count  T   M   R

 4    No  Yes  W
 2    Yes No   W
 7    No  Yes  B
 155  Yes Yes  B
 9    No  No   W
 3    Yes No   W
 7    No  No   B
 2    Yes No   B
```

So What I want is...

```
T   M   R

No Yes  W
No Yes  W
No Yes  W
No Yes  W
Yes No  W
Yes No  W
No Yes  B 
.   .   . (x7)
Yes Yes B
.   .   . (x155)
No  No  W
.   .   . (x9)
Yes No  W
Yes No  W
Yes No  W
No  No  B 
.   .   . (x7)
Yes No  B
Yes No  B
```

To perform logistic regression, I need individual datas, but instead of individual datas, I have counts. How would I make a new data frame so each datas can repeat as much according to its counts which is in the same row?

I think this is a easy for loop and if statement...but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: R is not called "R CRAN".  CRAN is related to R but your question has nothing to do with CRAN and probably shouldn't have the CRAN tag on it.

Comment: How is this different to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739542/how-to-repeat-strings-with-respect-to-count-in-cran-r) asked today? The accepted solution is in fact almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the indices as many times as your `Count` column:

```
> rep(1:nrow(data), data$Count)
  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 ... 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8
```

and use that to index the data.frame:

```
data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$Count),]
```

If you want to remove the `Count` column, do this:

```
data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$Count), -1]
```

Comment: When I tried your other function and I set the t equals to the sum of the total it gave me error that argument must be coercible to non-negative integer....I will try this one

Comment: @user1896642 yeah, that was a typo, I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, this works to use it as a separate datas for logistic but Count column is still showing...hmm let me think how to remove this...

Comment: Urbano Thank you very much I understand clearly now..Again Thank you for your help. I can't vote up but when I receive 3 more reputation I promise I will vote up for your answer.