# Increase speed with rbindlist does not work with two for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, rbind

I have a dataset that looks like this one:

```
test <- data.table(Weight=sample(x = c(20:100),500,replace = T),y=rnorm(500),z=rnorm(500))

> head(test)
   Weight          y           z
1:     87 -0.7946846 -0.03136408
2:     97  1.6570765  0.61080309
3:     80  1.1592073 -0.09389739
4:     23 -0.0268602 -1.36896141
5:     32  1.3171078 -2.19978789
6:     78 -0.1961162  0.62026338
```

I want to duplicate each row as many times as the value under weight.I have achieved this with the following code: (I included a progressbar)

```
system.time(
  for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
    for (j in 1:test[i,]$Weight){
      Testoutcome <- rbind(Testoutcome, test[i,])
    }
  })
user  system elapsed 
  32.91    0.08   33.57
```

I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697700/how-to-speed-up-rbind) that explains that rbindlist is much faster than rbind. So I modified the code like this:

```
system.time(
  for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
    for (j in 1:test[i,]$Weight){
      Testoutcome <- rbindlist(list(Testoutcome, test[i,]))
    }
  })
user  system elapsed 
  27.72    0.05   28.31
```

So it seems not to be so effective. My actual dataset is about 1.000 times larger and the query takes forever... Any ideas how to speed up? Maybe I should get the bind outside the loop?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25148/how-to-expand-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Ah, and here's an exact match, though it doesn't ask about speed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518728/r-replicate-each-row-of-an-r-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fast, and is quite simple:

```
test[rep(1:.N,Weight)]
```

Comment: Thanks, was focussing too much on rbind and rbindlist.