# Using dplyr/purrr instead of for loops to mask multiple columns and/or expand rows

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Essentially its about using bitmask/binary columns and row-oriented operations against a data table/frame: Firstly, to construct a logical vector from a combination of selected columns that can be used to mask a charcter vector to represent 'what' columns are flagged. Secondly, row-expansion - given a count in one column, prouce a data table that contains the original row data replicated that number of times.

For summarising the flags using a row-wise bitmask, which uses purrr:reduce to concatenate the row-represented flags, I cannot find a succinct method to do this in a %>% chain rather than a separate for loop. I suspect a purrr::map is required but I cannot get it/the syntax right.

For the row expansion, the nested for loop has appalling performance and I cannot find a way for dplyr/purrr to, row-wise, replicate that row a given number of times per row. A map and other functions would need to produce and append multiple rows which, I don't think map is capable of.

The following code produces the required output - but, apart from performance issues (especially regarding row expansion), I'd like to be able to do this as vectorised operations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(C1=c(0,0,1,0,1,0),
         C2=c(1,0,0,0,0,1),
         C3=c(0,1,0,0,1,0),
         C4=c(0,1,1,0,0,0),
         C5=c(0,0,0,0,1,1),
         N=c(5,2,6,8,1,3),
         Spurious = '')
flags <- c("Scratching Head","Screaming",
       "Breaking Keyboard","Coffee Break",
       "Giving up")

# Summarise states
flagSummary <- function(dt){
    interim <- dt %>%
            dplyr::mutate_at(vars(C1:C5),.funs=as.logical) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(States=c(""))

    for(i in 1:nrow(interim)){
        interim$States[i] <-
        flags[as.logical(interim[i,1:5])] %>%
        purrr::reduce(~ paste(.x, .y, sep = ","),.init="") %>%
        stringr::str_replace("^[,]","") }
      dplyr::select(interim,States,N) }

summary <- flagSummary(dt)
View(summary)

# Expand states
expandStates <- function(dt){
    interim <- dt %>%
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(C1:C5), .funs=as.logical) %>%
    dplyr::select_at(vars(C1:C5,N)) %>%
    data.table::setnames(.,append(flags,"Count"))

    expansion <- interim[0,1:5]
    for(i in 1:nrow(interim)){
        for(j in 1:interim$Count[i]){
        expansion <- bind_rows(expansion, interim[i,1:5]) } }
      expansion }

expansion <- expandStates(dt)
View(expansion)
```

As stated, the code produces the expected result. I'd 'like' to see the same without resorting to for loops and whilst being able to chain the functions into the initial mutate/selects.

Answer (score 0):

As for the row expansion of the expandStates function, the answer is proffered here [Replicate each row of data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518728/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each) by A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1.

Essentially, the nested for loop is simply replaced by

```
interim[rep(rownames(interim[,1:5]),interim$Count),][1:5]
```

On my 'actual' data, this reduces user systime from 28.64 seconds to 0.06 to produce some 26000 rows.